# socket send and retrieve

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Good day all i am new to java and i would like to know if someone can help me with this problem
I have a server and it receives info from the client but my if statement to check the value that was passed doesn't work.

Here is my code for the server.

```
   Session(Socket s){
        soc = s;
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));

            pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream()),true);
            pw.println("Welcome");           
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }


        if(runner == null){
            runner = new Thread(this);
            runner.start();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        while(runner == Thread.currentThread()){
            try{
                String input = br.readLine().toString();
                    if(input != null){
                        String output = Protocol.ProcessInput(input);
                        pw.println(output);
                        System.out.println(input);


                        if(output.equals("Good Bye")){
                            runner = null;
                            pw.close();
                            br.close();
                            soc.close();
                        }
                 **This if statement doesn't work   ↓**
                        if(Protocol.ProcessInput(input).equalsIgnoreCase("tiaan")){
                           // System.exit(0);
                            System.out.println("Got tiaan!!!");
                        }
                    }

            }catch(IOException ie){
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
        }
    }


}

class Protocol{
     static String ProcessInput(String input){
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello")){
            return "Well hello to you to";
        }else{
            return "Good bye";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Let's have a look at that if statement:

```
if(Protocol.ProcessInput(input).equalsIgnoreCase("tiaan")){
    // System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("Got tiaan!!!");
}
```

That code is equivalent to the following:

```
String output = Protocol.ProcessInput(input)
if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("tiaan")){
    // System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("Got tiaan!!!");
}
```

So the output from `ProcessInput` is compared to the string "tiaan" and looking at `ProcessInput` shows that it will never return that string. So maybe you actually want to do something else, for example compare the input directly with "tiaan" or change the implementation of `ProcessInput`:

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("tiaan")){
    // System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("Got tiaan!!!");
}
```

Note that you can get a NullPointerException when you read the input:

```
//Change this:
String input = br.readLine().toString();
//Into this:
String input = br.readLine();
```

`readLine` already gives you a string so you don't need toString at the end. If `readLine` gives you null, which it does when you reach the end of the stream, then the invocation of `toString` will cause a NullPointerException. On the next line you actually check if input is null which is good but using your code the error will occur before that check.